# Masking non-NDVI feastures such as clouds, water and infrastructures

Tags: qgis, raster, ndvi, masking

I would like to calculate the NDVI value for my study area, however there is cloud cover which makes it unable to calculate the NDVI.

How do I mask all the non-ndvi features such as water, infrastructures,  roads etc in order to calculate the ndvi and use interpolation to fill in the missing data?

I am using LANDSAT 7 IMAGES and QGIS. There's reasons behind why I need to use LANDSAT 7 for my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

If you download your Landsat 7 data from ESPA USGA (https://espa.cr.usgs.gov/), you will be provided with Pixel Quality Assurance layer and Landsat Meta Data File (MTL) for each scene. This layer contains information about quality features (such as clear pixels, cloud, cloud shadows, snow etc.).

For masking, you can use 'Cloud Masking' plugin in QGIS (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CloudMasking/). The plugin can be installed from Plugins menu. The whole masking process will be completed in 3 steps; 
1) Open and Load option: load MTL file and bands if needed
2) Filters and mask: select a filter such as QA band and generate a mask
3) Apply and save: apply mask and save outputs

A step by step guide can be found on on this page (https://smbyc.bitbucket.io/qgisplugins/cloudmasking/how_to_use/).